# Looking for a certain key in all objects nestings

Tags: javascript, loops, self-reference

I'm trying to build a function that will look for given property key in all nestings of an object and later on, return the value of given, found, key.

There is the dataSet:

```
let data = {
    'Test123': {
        'Another Test': {},
        'Test some more': {
            'Still testing?': {
                'Yeah...': {}
            },
            'Never ending story': {}
        }
    },
    'Leeeeeeeeeeeroy!' : {
        'Jenkins': {}
    }
};
```

And there is a function:

```
function findProperty (keyUnknown, dataPile) {
    let found;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataPile)) {
        if (keyUnknown === key) {
            found = value;
            break;
        } else {
            found = findProperty(keyUnknown, value);
        }
    }
    return found;
}
let questionsToRender = findProperty(key, data);
```

Given key to find 'Test some more', function returns undefined, could someone please take a look at it? I have been stuck on it for quite a lot already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to also check if the `found` is undefined or not in else condition.

```js
let data = {"Test123":{"Another Test":{},"Test some more":{"Still testing?":{"Yeah...":{}},"Never ending story":{}}},"Leeeeeeeeeeeroy!":{"Jenkins":{}}}

function findProperty(keyUnknown, dataPile) {
  let found;
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataPile)) {
    if (keyUnknown === key) {
      found = value;
      break;
    } else if (!found) {
      found = findProperty(keyUnknown, value);
    }
  }
  return found;
}

let questionsToRender = findProperty('Test some more', data);
console.log(questionsToRender)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the missing check, you could take a more compact approach and return early on find.

```js
function find(key, object) {
    var value;
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;
    if (key in object) return object[key];
    Object.values(object).some(v => value = find(key, v));
    return value;
}

let data = { Test123: { 'Another Test': {}, 'Test some more': { 'Still testing?': { 'Yeah...': {} }, 'Never ending story': {} } }, 'Leeeeeeeeeeeroy!' : { Jenkins: {} } };

console.log(find('Still testing?', data));
```